# hide all element that have class= ' contact ' and keep just 5 items JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to hide all element that have `class='contact'`  and keep just 5 items using js or jQuery

I have this button in html :

```
 <div class="text-center mt-4">
   <a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg hide">hide</a>
</div>
```

and this in script :

```
const thumbnail = $(".contact");
let hiddenThumbnails = 0;

function hideThumbnailsUntil(index) {
  for (var i = hiddenThumbnails; i >= index; i--) {
    if (i < thumbnail.length) {
      $(thumbnail[i]).addClass('visible');
      hiddenThumbnails--;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

hideThumbnailsUntil(4);

$(".hide").on("click", function() {
  showThumbnailsUntil(hiddenThumbnails + 4)

  if (hiddenThumbnails === thumbnails.length) {
    $(".hide").fadeOut();
  }
})
```

I added this button but it doesn't work. It doesn't hide all elements that have `class='contact'`  and keep just 5 items

how to fix that ?

Comment: Is there something else that increments `hiddenThumbnails`? If not, `i >= index` will never be true.

Comment: thanks all really all your answer helped me

Comment: i have other question with show more / hide buttons please can you help me with that ? please check my question here because it's have codes also codeshare.io/ayzjyo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `:nth-child(n+6)` selector if the parent is the same of all elements.

```js
$("#hide").on("click", function() {
  $(".contact:nth-child(n+6)").hide("slow");
});

$("#show").on("click", function() {
  $(".contact:nth-child(n+6)").show("slow");
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contact {
 padding: 12px;
 margin: 20px;
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 1</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 2</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 3</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 4</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 5</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 6</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 7</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer is better than mine. Kudos!

Comment: yes this good , thanks this helped me , i have other question please can you help me with that ? 

please check my question here because it's have codes also 

https://codeshare.io/ayzjyo

Comment: I have modified the answer. Added button to show elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Vanilla JS:

```js
const contactElements = document.querySelectorAll('.contact')

contactElements.forEach((elem, i) => {
    // If i is less than or equal to 4, that means the current iteration is one of the first 5 elements.
    if (i > 4) {
        elem.style.display = 'none'
        // Or add a class
        // elem.classList.add('hidden')
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks this helped me , i have other question please can you help me with that ? 

please check my question here because it's have codes also 

https://codeshare.io/ayzjyo

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that:

```js
//i want hide all element that have class= ' contact ' and keep just 5 items using js or jQuery
document.querySelectorAll('.hide')[0].addEventListener('click', function() { // click event
    let el2hide = document.querySelectorAll('.contact'); // the class we want to hide
    for (var i=0; i < el2hide.length; i++) { 
        if (i > 4) { // start after 5
          el2hide[i].classList.add('hidden'); // hide them
        };
    }
});
```

```css
a {color: blue; text-decoration: underline;}
.hidden {opacity: 0.1}
```

```html
<div class="text-center mt-4">
<a role="presentation" type="button" class="btn btn-lg hide">click to "hide"</a>
</div>
<h1>Deom .contact elements:</h1>
<ol>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
<li class="contact">contact</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: thanks this helped me , i have other question please can you help me with that ? 

please check my question here because it's have codes also 

https://codeshare.io/ayzjyo

Answer (score 1):

I translated Rohit's answer to vanilla JS with the `:nth-child(n+6)` selector.

```js
const contactElements = document.querySelectorAll('.contact:nth-child(n+6)');
const hideBtn = document.querySelector('#hide');

hideBtn.addEventListener('click', () => contactElements.forEach(elm => elm.style.display = 'none'));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.contact {
 padding: 12px;
 margin: 20px;
 background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 1</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 2</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 3</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 4</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 5</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 6</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 7</div>
  <div class="contact">Thumbnail 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks this helped me , i have other question please can you help me with that ? 

please check my question here because it's have codes also 

https://codeshare.io/ayzjyo

Comment: you can post the other question here on SO and I would love to help you with it. I just can't find your question in all this code

Comment: here is my question can you check it please 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179244/show-more-hide-button-keep-show-data-and-hide-more-than-once-not-once-time-i